# Plotting and GroupBy methods

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am just learning to take advantage of DataFrames in Pandas and I would like to use GroupBy methods to produce plots of the following:

I have two dataframes, one for the x-axis information and one for the y. In each dataframe there are three versions of the data, say 'A', 'B', 'C'. I need a plot of y vs x for each of those (i.e. three lines).

Example code:

```
df_x

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A     100  non-null values
B      100  non-null values
C    100  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)

df_y

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A     100  non-null values
B      100  non-null values
C    100  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
```

Is there a quick way to produce the desired plot avoiding for loops and using Pandas methods? I'm thinking of merging both frames and using GroupBy methods, but I don't know how to go about doing that exactly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this plot directly using pyplot:

```
In [11]: plot(df_x, df_y)  # matplotlib.pyplot.plot
Out[11]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x109c02910>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x109c02b90>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x109c02ed0>]
```

It seems you need to set the legend after though:

```
pylab.legend(df_x.columns)
```

If you really wanted to reshape your data into a form to use `.plot`, perhaps you could use:

```
In [21]: df_x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[2,3,4]], columns=list('ABC'))

In [22]: df_y = pd.DataFrame([[2,6,1],[4,9,4]], columns=list('ABC'))

In [23]: pd.DataFrame({'x': df_x.stack(), 'y': df_y.stack()}).reset_index(level=1).pivot('x', 'level_1', 'y')
Out[23]:
level_1   A   B   C
x
1         2 NaN   1
2         4   6 NaN
3       NaN   9 NaN
4       NaN NaN   4
```

*This is going to be considerably less efficient (take up a lot more space than it needs to), since it contains a lot of missing data.*

Comment: That works! I guess I got way too excited with GroupBy methods and wanted to use them everywhere. However, how can I pass plotting style for each of the columns?